# Bootstrap 3 and quicksand integration issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, quicksand

I am trying to simply integrate quicksand to my new bootstrap 3 site.
I am having issues with my  holder which holds all the portfolio items.
I am using bootstrap 3 classes: **thumbnail** and **col-sm-3** to float the gallery in a way that bootstrap recognize and treats it responsively.

my issue is that my  holder always get dynamic height and width.
height is not a problem here but the width changes all the time and shrinks my images.

I was looking at tons of quicksands examples around the web and no one has that issue

here is a link to my portfolio page:
http://www.tipoos.com/bs/portfolio.html

can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here?
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is due to the height of the row ( parent of ul.thumbnails )

Try this :

```
$(function() {

  var minHeight = $(".thumbnails").height();

  $(".row").css({"height":minHeight});

});
```

=> When your page is loaded, you give to your container the maximum height

I did not try it, tell me if it is ok !

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work unfortunately. thanks a lot for the help